# Angular observable service call giving undefined error

Tags: typescript, angular-services, http-get

I have a service that makes an API call which retruns collection of valid users.
below given is code snippet from service and component.

Error I am getting while mapping response to local variable defined in service is-->
ValidUserCollection is undefined

Note: My call to service is successfull and I do get the response status as 200 and Ok : true.
only issue seems to be when I am mapping the response to local variable defined in service.

Any advise as what I might be missing or doing wrong ?

Following is my service code for method defined in service.

```
 constructor(private http: Http){
        this.ValidUsersCollection = [];
    }

    GetAllUsers(): Observable<User[]>
    {
       return this.http.get('http://localhost:8055/api/user/GetAllUsers/', { headers: this.getHeaders() })
         .map(this.mapPersons)
    }

mapPersons(response:Response): User[]
    {
        return response.json().map(this.ValidUsersCollection)
     }

    private getHeaders() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');  
        return headers;
    }


code from my component
    this.userSrv.GetAllUsers()
.subscribe(allusers => this.allUsersCollection = allusers);
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
let ValidUsersCollection : User[] = [];
constructor(private http: Http){}

GetAllUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
       return this.http.get('http://localhost:8055/api/user/GetAllUsers/', { headers: this.getHeaders() })
         .map(res =>{
           return res.json().map(items => { this.ValidUsersCollection = items });
     });
}
```

Comment: still error is same... I get undefined .. please note that I could not declare ValidUsersCollection as var or let as that is class member... and class member can either be private/public or nothing....

Comment: @user9401912 first thing you should know is you shouldn't use a defined array of service in your component, in service you should just write your http requests and in your component subscribe get the result and map it in your array.

Comment: I am not using service member into my component... as you can see in my component code above,   I am calling service method and  subscribing the response to local component variable...  not sure what else I am doing wrong